# WebView Android Null exception

Tags: java, android, webview

So the error is

```
06-30 11:51:08.690: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 11:51:08.690: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     
at com.bd.krowd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
```

And my code here is:`

```
String url ="http://themeforest.net/item/forum-website-html-template/full_screen_preview/7968760";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

Line 54 is

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

So what must be done?

Comment: do you have a webview with id `webView1` in your xml ?

Comment: Is R.id.webView1 in the current layout?

Comment: can you post your layout file?

Comment: view is probably null.
Is the layout set correctly before calling findViewById?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BMfhRW8u

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Are you calling setContentView before findViewById ?

Comment: Ermn content view is of main activity... But I don't know how to add the webview to the main activity. Because my main activity is 
http://pastebin.com/L5tUcX7h

Comment: It seems that you have not added WebView to Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must be null!
webview or the WebSettings object returned by getSettings().

```
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

view can be null if R.id.webView1  cannot be found

have you called :

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourWebviewLayout);
```

before in your oncreate??

Answer (score 1):

if ur webview is in activity... change the code as below...

```
String url ="http://themeforest.net/item/forum-website-html-template/full_screen_preview/7968760";
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl(url);
```

call on create before adding this snippet..

Comment: That's what I wrote haha.